# sql server 2008 management studio not checking the syntax of my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

As always, there will be a reasonable explanation for my surprise, but till then....

I have this query

```
delete from Photo  where hs_id  in (select hs_id  from HotelSupplier where id = 142)
```

which executes just fine (later i found out that the entire photo table was empty)

but the strange thing: there is no field `hs_id` in HotelSupplier, it is called `hs_key`!

So when i execute the last part

```
select hs_id  from HotelSupplier where id = 142
```

separately (select that part of the query with the mouse and hit F5), i get an error, but when i use it in the `in` clause, it doesn't!

I wonder if this is normal behaviour?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is taking the value of `hs_id`  from the outer query.

It is perfectly valid to have a query that doesn't project any columns from the selected table in its `select` list.

For example

```
select 10 from HotelSupplier where id = 142
```

would return a result set with as many rows as matched the `where` clause and the value `10` for all rows.

Unqualified column references are resolved from the closest scope outwards so this just gets treated as a correlated sub query.

The result of this query will be to delete all rows from `Photo` where `hs_id` is not null as long as HotelSupplier has at least one row where id = 142 (and so the subquery returns at least one row)

It might be a bit clearer if you consider what the effect of this is

```
delete from Photo  where Photo.hs_id  in (select Photo.hs_id)
```

This is of course equivalent to

```
delete from Photo where Photo.hs_id = Photo.hs_id
```

By the way this is far and away the most common "bug" that I personally have seen erroneously reported on Microsoft Connect. Erland Sommarskog includes it in his [wishlist](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#columnprefixes) for `SET STRICT_CHECKS ON`

Comment: +1 - Just wanted to explicitly point out a good practice in your example - including the table names for each of the columns (two part identifiers) throughout your query.  Good practice in general, invaluable practice in delete statements!

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. imho it's weird though, that (in your simplified version also) the notn-existing 'select Photo.hs_id' doesn't generate an error

Comment: @Michel - It isn't non existent. It is treated as a correlated sub query and evaluated for each row using the value passed in from the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

It's a strong argument for keeping column names consistent between tables. As @Martin says, the SQL syntax allows column names to be resolved from the outer query, when there's no match in the inner query. This is a boon when writing correlated subqueries, but can trip you up sometimes (as here)

Comment: yeah, absolutely agree, the consistnecy in this db is far away. textkey, textid, text_key, text_id, hsid, hs_id etc. brrrrr

Comment: Of course, that doesn't help if you type in the wrong table name that doesn't have the right at all