# Problem with "NOT IN" in a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to find all id's from the OldTable that doesn't exist in the NewTable
Why won't this query find the id?

```
SELECT old_id FROM OldTable WHERE old_id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM NewTable)
```

By them selves they return this

```
--Returns the id 18571
SELECT old_id FROM OldTable WHERE old_id = 18571

 --Returns nothing  
SELECT id FROM NewTable WHERE id = 18571
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Both columns are of type `int` and primary keys.

**SOLVED**

*The id column had null's in them, I was just being ignorant =/*

These works:

```
SELECT old_id FROM OldTable EXCEPT SELECT id FROM NewTable  

SELECT * FROM old_table ot WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM new_table nt WHERE nt.id = ot.old_id)
```

These doesn't work:

```
SELECT old_id FROM OldTable LEFT JOIN NewTable ON old_id = id WHERE id IS NULL  

SELECT old_id FROM OldTable WHERE old_id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM NewTable)
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM NewTable` probably returns a `NULL`. This will mean your query won't return any results.

Comment: are the datatype of both columns exactly the same.. are you missing cast or maybe some small formatting adjustment?

Comment: The sub query doesn't return any nulls. Both tables has NOT NULL set on the id columns

Comment: Which database system do you use? Do you execute the queries directly on the database (for instance using SQLyog) or do you use some script?

Comment: @Niklas - Can you try `SELECT old_id FROM OldTable EXCEPT 
SELECT id FROM NewTable`?

Comment: Hey Martin, that worked just as well as wildplasser's query below.

Comment: @Niklas - In your `NOT IN` version might you have been accidentally referencing the column belonging to `OldTable` in the inner sub query instead of referencing the `id` column belonging to `NewTable`?

Comment: @Martin - Well there's something going on here but I don't know what =) (Don't think there's anything wrong in the references though)

Comment: @Niklas - Please post your actual queries.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks, you were right with your first comment, it had null's in the id column. I checked the wrong column when I looked for the `NOT NULL` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM old_table ot
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM new_table nt
   WHERE nt.new_key = ot.old_key
   );
```

Comment: The difference in behaviour between `NOT IN (subquery)` and `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` is due to the presence of nulls.

Answer (score 2):

The difference can be attributed to the presence of nulls.

Consider these two simplified queries, noting the predicate for both is `NULL = 1` which evaluates to UNKNOWN which is handled differently by `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` respectively:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OldTable
 WHERE NULL NOT IN (SELECT 1 FROM OldTable);

 SELECT *
  FROM OldTable
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OldTable WHERE NULL = 1);
```

The first returns no rows because `NOT IN (subquery)` evaluated to FALSE.

The first returns all rows because `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` evaluated to TRUE.

Conclusion: avoid nulls.

Comment: They say the columns are not nullable though. I suspect they are hitting the same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4594733/73226

Comment: @Martin Smith: but you are correct that it could have been the same issue as the one you linked to, one I hadn't come across myself (which really should result in a syntax error IMO!) so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your query doesn't give you the desired result, but I do know that using `NOT IN` is not very efficient. You would be better of using a joins:

```
SELECT old_id 
FROM OldTable 
LEFT JOIN NewTable
    ON old_id = id
WHERE id IS NULL
```

Comment: "not very efficient" -- in what way, bearing in mind you don;t even know which SQL product they are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT old_id FROM OLDTable WHERE id not in (SELECT id from NewTable);
```

You are using old_id in where condition in the first query and you are using id in second query

Comment: Mistake by me when I entered the query on to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
select oldtable.id as orginal, newtable.id as new 
from oldtable 
left outer join newtable 
on oldtable.id =newtable.id 
where new is null
```

AFAIK (and i am not an expert - check my rep ;-) left outer join is a good technique for this.. it will *may* perform a not in and does not require a sub-select

@onedaywhen kindly points out that this is not always the case e.g. in SQL Server EXISTS() can be more efficient.

Comment: "it will out perform a not in" -- I note your disclaimer but how can you know this if you don't even know which SQL product they are using?

Comment: @onedaywhen very good point.. just hear say, its what I was told, sub select & not in = bad.  Does that vary depending on the product/engine?

Comment: Yes, among other things. `EXISTS()` is good for SQL Server because it *may* short circuit but may not be best every time.

Comment: @onedaywhen oh, cool.. I will update the answer for what it is worth.  BTW did you get caught out by new *at*username autocomplete? ;-) (or is that another case of me being a newbie?)

Comment: Yes, I do keep getting caught out but in my defence it is a relatively recent change and I'm an old hand ;)