# SQL Server 2008 subquery with error. Still works the main query

Tags: sql-server-2008, subquery

Ok, maybe I'm a noob in sql, but I can't figure out why this should work:

I've Table1 like:

```
IDRecord (PK), Description, IDTable2 (FK)
```

and a Table2 like this:

```
IDRecord (PK), Description
```

with Table1.IDTable2 as FK to Table2.IDRecord.

Then I've a very simple query:

```
select * from Table1
where IDTable2 not in (select IDMispelledRecord from Table2)
```

I've made a syntax error! There's not a column called IDMispelledRecord in Table2, and if I execute the subquery alone, it returns to me

```
Invalid column name 'IDMispelledRecord'.
```

But if I execute the WHOLE query it doesn't raise an error, simply returns 0 rows.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question doesn't show this (please post your actual code in future) `Table1` must have a column called `IDMispelledRecord`.

Your subquery is referencing that column from the outer query.

Comment: oh Lord, you're right. There's a field in the upper table with the same name I wrongly used in the subquery...

Comment: @tanathos - [This can be particular dangerous in a `DELETE`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query/4594765#4594765)