# T-SQL Deletes all rows from a table when subquery is malformed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql server 2008 management studio not checking the syntax of my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query)

I ran across an issue today where a subquery was bad and the result was all rows from the parent table were deleted.

```
TableA
ID,
Text,
GUID

TableB
ID,
TableAID,
Text

delete from TableB
where id in (
  select TableAID
  from TableA
  where GUID = 'fdjkhflafdhf'
)
```

If you run the subquery by itself you get an error since the column (TableAID) doesn't exist in Table A.  If you run the full query - it deletes all records from table B without an error.

I also tried the following queries which removed 0 records (expected)

```
delete from TableB where id in (null) 
delete from TableB where id in (select null)
```

Can someone explain to my why this is occurring when the query is malformed?  Why does it seem to evaluate to true?

Note: This was tested on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Good question, I have run across this before as well.

Comment: NB: I am assuming that `TableB` does in fact have a column called `somebadcolumn`? If so you have missed that out in the question.

Comment: The column does not exist.  I updated the question have more clarity.

Comment: @tsells - But does it exist in the **other** table? I'm sure it must or this would indeed be a huge bug.

Comment: @tsells - You've not answered Martin's question. We are aware `somebadcolumn` doesn't exist in `TableA`, but does it exist in `TableB`?

Comment: I updated the question.  You are correct that the column exists in the other table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `TableAID` doesn't exist in `TableA`, the query is using the column from `TableB`. Therefore the query is the same as:

```
delete from TableB
where id in (
  select TableB.TableAID
  from TableA
  where GUID = 'fdjkhflafdhf'
)
```

So in essence it's doing:

```
delete from TableB
where id in (TableAID)
```

If you are using sub-queries its best to mention your table names when referencing. The following **WILL** throw an exception:

```
 delete from TableB
    where id in (
      select TableA.TableAID
      from TableA
      where TableA.GUID = 'fdjkhflafdhf'
    )
```

Furthermore I would use an alias so that we know which query we are referring to:

```
 delete from TableB
    where id in (
      select a.TableAID
      from TableA a
      where a.GUID = 'fdjkhflafdhf'
    )
```