# in-clause scoping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scoping, in-clause

I am doing some work for a company that has SQL Server 2008. One of their stored procedures references (or appears to reference) a column that does not exist, and yet there is no error.

The query has this structure:

```
         select col1, col2 from FOO
         where col3 in
         (select id from BAZ where datecreated between @date1 and @date2)
```

** BAZ does not contain a column called [datecreated] but FOO does.**  If I change the query to qualify the column name, as follows, there IS an error:

```
        select col1, col2 from FOO
         where b in
         (select id from BAZ where BAZ.datecreated between @date1 and @date2)
```

If this is the by-design behavior, could someone please point me to the relevant documentation? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design.

It is perfectly valid to access a column from the outer query  in a [correlated sub query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx). This might be desired semantics in some cases.

Comment: +1 - It's normally considered good practice to qualify that column with the table name from the outer query for clarity, though.

Comment: @JNK - Yep, and failure to observe this [can lead to empty tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query/4594765#4594765) if used in a `DELETE`!