# SQL Server not returning an error why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

Could someone please explain why the following query runs and does not return an error in SQL server 2012? When column BADCOLUMN does not exist in Table sometable?

```
SELECT  et
       ,mdt
FROM csv_import as a
where et IN (2,73) 
  AND siteid IN (
                 select BADCOLUMN
                 from sometable
                  where SN in ('a','b','c')
                )
```

If you run just the subquery

```
select BADCOLUMN 
from sometable 
where SN in ('a','b','c')
```

You will receive an error stating the column does not exist.  But if you run the full query 
you will not receive an error and that section of the where clause gets ignored

To me the full query should not run as a section of it contains an error?
Opinions or Reasons?

Comment: Could it be database context?  It doesn't look like your objects are fully qualified.

Comment: In the actual issue they are I obfuscated this a little

Comment: Are you sure `BADCOLUMN` really doesn't exists? are you not doing `select 'BADCOLUMN'`?

Comment: Shot in the dark...is BADCOLUMN a column in csv_import?

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan (Control + M before running query)? It should contain the plan for grabbing BADCOLUMN from sometable.

Comment: Alias your subquery table then check(select t.BADCOLUMN
                 from sometable as t
                  where t.SN in ('a','b','c'))

Comment: @Rahul: Can you please look into the last answer in the below post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849612/wrong-case-in-subquery-column-name-causes-incorrect-results-but-no-error

Comment: @knkarthick24, that would be the case only when there is a similar column present in both outer/inner table. Which may not be the case all time and not at least in this scenario.

Comment: @Rahul - What if the `csv_import` table has column named with `BADCOLUMN`

Comment: It actually does but I am not sure why that should matter since the select is a sub query against the table

Comment: @Rahul Subqueries allow you to make reference to a field from your outer query which is the cause of this issue!!

Comment: @Rahul You are wrong. If the column exists in the outer table, then SQL Server [**won't**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b12e6/2) throw an error

Comment: @knkarthick24, post that as answer.