# SQL Server query weird behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, execution, query-expressions

I ran into a strange behaviour by a query in SQL Server

I have two tables `PrepaidTransactions` and `BillingData` and I am executing the following query

```
Select * 
from PrepaidTransactions 
where customer_Id in
                  (Select customer_Id 
                   from BillingData 
                   where CommunityId = 10004)
```

The column `customer_Id` doesn't belong to table `BillingData`. Instead of showing error the query is executing and returning all the records from the `PrepaidTransactions` table

But when I run the following query

```
Select customer_Id 
from BillingData 
where CommunityId = 10004
```

it is showing an error

> Invalid column name 'customer_Id'.

Can anyone please let me know why the first query is not showing any error?

Comment: The first query runs because `customer_Id` unambiguously resolves to `PrepaidTransactions.customer_Id`

Comment: I am pretty sure the result set is not what you are expecting

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server 2008 management studio not checking the syntax of my query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou , yes the result set not what iam expecting.

Comment: @MartinSmith , yes it is possible duplicate , but before posting this question i checked and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these two articles answer your question.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/542289/subquery-with-error-does-not-cause-outer-select-to-fail

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298674

This is expected behavior because your column name is not bound to a table. Therefore, if it can be resolved in the outer table (which in your query's case, it can), then the subquery doesn't fail. If you specify the table BillingData.customer_Id, you will get a failure. The articles say to follow this practice to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: the kb article from the second link states that,
`In the case of an unqualified column name, the query optimizer assumes that the query is a correlated subquery` , now i understand what is the exact reason and why one should use fully-qualified column name in a sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

wow!  I think that in your first case, customer_Id was being pulled from the outer query.  You can test that by doing a table prefix:

```
Select * from PrepaidTransactions where customer_Id in
(Select PrepaidTransactions.customer_Id from BillingData where CommunityId = 10004)
```

gets same results, but

```
Select * from PrepaidTransactions where customer_Id in
(Select BillingData.customer_Id from BillingData where CommunityId = 10004)
```

I bet that errors?