# SQL using a select query to delete

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE * 
FROM foo 
WHERE classid = SELECT classid 
                FROM market_items 
                WHERE steamid = '76561198089201925'
```

How can we then use this select query to delete all the rows in another table which have a classid as one of the selected class ids.

Comment: Please elaborate in your question. Do the query already solve something, are you getting an error or unwanted behaviour? Do steamID have a single classID or multiple classID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM foo 
where classid in (SELECT classid 
                  from market_items 
                  where steamid='76561198089201925')
```

Comment: [you should always use table aliases here to avoid unpleasant surprises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4594733/73226)