# Linked server NOT IN query confusion

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, collation, linked-server

Lets say I have 100 items in the Products table that have Status= 'New' when I run:

```
select * from Products where Status='New' and Product_GUID COLLATE DATABSE_DEFAULT IN (
SELECT Product_GUID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM [OracleLinkedServer]..[MAINDB].[VIEW_PRODUCTS]
)
```

I get 50 items in the result.

But when I run NOT IN like this

```
select * from Products where Status='New' and Product_GUID COLLATE DATABSE_DEFAULT NOT IN (
SELECT Product_GUID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM [OracleLinkedServer]..[MAINDB].[VIEW_PRODUCTS]
)
```

I get no items back, what I am expecting to get is the items that were not returned in the previous IN query, where am I going wrong here? Is the collation an issue?

Also the first query takes a while to return as it is going out to a linked server, but the second returns immediately as if it makes no attempt to get data from the linked server. The linked server is Oracle. 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you *sure* there are products that should be returned by the query? Have you looked at the execution plan of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of the following.

1. [The subquery returns a `NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231731/73226)
2. `[OracleLinkedServer]..[MAINDB].[VIEW_PRODUCTS]` does not contain a column called `Product_GUID` so [this is resolved from the outer scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query).

(My guess is the second from your description)

Comment: There were NULLS in the subquery, added WHERE Product_GUID IS NOT NULL and its working fine. Thanks