# Delete from SQL table where ID is found from conditions applied to another table

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-delete

First of all, I don't know if the title is right but let me show you what I want and I will correct it as suggested.
So, I have 2 tables:

- table1

  - ID, subid, name
- table2

  - ID

What I want is to delete any element from `table2` that has `ID` equal to `subid` in `table1`, where `table1.name` is equal to a specified value.

If I have these elements in `table1`

```
ID    subid    name
1 ... 1 ...... name1  
2 ... 3 ...... name2  
3 ... 2 ...... name1  
4 ... 1 ...... name2
```

and these rows in `table2`

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

I would like to remove those elements in `table2` with ID = subid, when name = *name1*, which means elements 1 and 2.

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE  ID = (SELECT subid
             FROM   table1
             WHERE  NAME = "name1")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete using joins as well, so yup very possible.

You can identify the (to be) deleted records first with:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.subId
    and  t1.name = 'whatever'
```

then perform the delete as such:

```
delete t2
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.subId
   and t1.name = 'whatever'
```

@eckes see my fiddle with the syntax that I'm using to see it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/260a5

Comment: @eckes it does, look at the fiddle i posted.  It's valid syntax

Comment: hm, the double from does at least not work on oracle, hm.

Answer (score 7):

You were very close.

You just need [`= ANY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) rather than `=` as the subquery can return more than one row [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89b3f/1).

```
DELETE 
FROM table2
WHERE  ID = ANY (SELECT t1.subid
                 FROM   table1 t1
                 WHERE  t1.name = 'name1')
```

Though this is more commonly expressed using `IN`

```
DELETE 
FROM table2
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT t1.subid
              FROM   table1 t1
              WHERE  t1.name = 'name1')
```

A couple of other changes I made to your posted query...

1. I always ensure that column references in subqueries use two part names to avoid [unfortunate surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4594733/73226).
2. You should use single quotes to delimit string literals so it works under default [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) settings and is not interpreted as referencing a column called `name1`.

Comment: you can also use MAX(t1.subid) to avoid the set oeration.

Comment: @eckes - That would change the semantics. It would just end up deleting rows where `ID =2` not `ID  IN (1,2)`