# SQL Server : how to delete based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a `USERS` table with active and inactive users and I also have another table called `Leaders` where team leaders are stored (so a list of users).

I want to delete those users in table `Leaders` that are inactive in table `users`.

Edit based on comments:

- `Users` table: ID and Active
- `Leaders` table: ID

Comment: what are the fields of your tables?

Comment: users table: id and active

Comment: leaders table: id

Comment: @user2426691 Edit the question

Comment: So is the ID column of the Leaders table the foreign key reference to the Users table?

Comment: @paparazzo Bossy guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `in` condition:

```
DELETE
FROM   leaders
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   users
              WHERE  active = 0 -- Or however you mark inactive users
             )
```

Comment: you should always use two part names here [to avoid a common error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4594733/73226)

Answer (score 2):

You can make joins in delete, similar to select:

```
delete ld
from leaders ld
join users us on ld.idUser = us.idUser
where us.active = 0
```