# Why is SQL Server not catching this? Typo in subquery causes accidental delete

Tags: sql-server, subquery, column-alias

I have a query with a subselect where I mistyped a column (id1 in the subselect). If the query is executed separatly SQL Server throws an error, which is correct and expected. However if executed as a subquery in the below context the typo is not catched - and in this case my table is cleared. Is this intented behaviour ?

```
CREATE TABLE #a1 (id1 INT);
CREATE TABLE #a2 (id2 INT);

INSERT INTO #a1 (id1) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO #a2 (id2) VALUES (1);

DELETE FROM #a1 WHERE id1 = (SELECT id1 FROM #a2 WHERE id2 = 1);

SELECT * FROM #a1 -- wow, the table is now empty
```

I expected an error to be thrown, instead the delete query was interpreted as

```
DELETE FROM #a1 WHERE id1 = id1.
```

Comment: duplicate of [sql server 2008 management studio not checking the syntax of my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns from the table declared in the outer query are available in the inner query. That's the same logic that comes into play when you build a correlated subquery.

So in this condition:

```
WHERE id1 = (SELECT id1 FROM #a2 WHERE id2=1)
```

The subquery returns as many recods as there are in table `#a2`, with `id1` coming from the outer query. As long as there is a unique record `#a2` that satisfies condition `id2 = 1`, this is actually equivalent to `WHERE id1 = id1`.

If you had prefixed the column names with table aliases, you would have received an error:

```
DELETE FROM #a1 t1 WHERE t1.id1 = (SELECT t2.id1 FROM #a2 t2 WHERE t2.id2 = 1);
```

Comment: that should teach me to always use table aliases. I accidently cleared a table with this mistakes with 1.2 Mio rows today, grr.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is intended behavior because your query explicitly looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM #a1 WHERE id1=(SELECT #a1.id1 FROM #a2 WHERE #a2.id2=1);
```

id1 is known in subquery because it belongs to #a1 and because for every row you select the same value exactly your receive:

```
delete from #a1 where id1=id1
```

But for subquery only (i.e. without delete section) - id1 is not known, so it shows error as expected.

Comment: yes, nearly the same - the subselect has to return at least one row however.

Answer (score 0):

`id1` is in table `A1`.

Change the `delete` query to a `select` and you will see.